# Twisted deferred vs blocking in web services

Tags: python, web-services, twisted, deferred

I'm struggling to produce the same behavior in web service code that uses Deferred objects as in code that does not.  My objective is to write a decorator that will delegate processing of any method (which is decoupled from Twisted) to the Twisted thread pool, so that the reactor is not blocked, without changing any of that method's semantics.

When an instance of class echo below is exposed as a web service, this code:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import defer, threads
from cgi import escape
from itertools import count

class echo(resource.Resource):
  isLeaf = True
  def errback(self, failure): return failure
  def callback1(self, request, value):
    #raise ValueError  # E1
    lines = ['<html><body>\n',
             '<p>Page view #%s in this session</p>\n' % (value,),
             '</body></html>\n']
    return ''.join(lines)
  def callback2(self, request, encoding):
    def execute(message):
      #raise ValueError  # E2
      request.write(message.encode(encoding))
      #raise ValueError  # E3
      request.finish()
      #raise ValueError  # E4
      return server.NOT_DONE_YET
    return execute
  def render_GET(self, request):
    content_type, encoding = 'text/html', 'UTF-8'
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', '%s; charset=%s' %
        tuple(map(str, (content_type, encoding))))
    s = request.getSession()
    if not hasattr(s, 'counter'):
      s.counter = count(1)
    d = threads.deferToThread(self.callback1, request, s.counter.next())
    d.addCallback(self.callback2(request, encoding))
    d.addErrback(self.errback)
    #raise ValueError  # E5
    return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

will display an HTML document to the browser when all the raise statements are commented out, and display a nicely formatted stack trace (which Twisted does for me) when the raise statement labelled "E5" is included.  That is what I want.  Likewise, if I do not use Deferred objects at all and place all the behavior from callback1 and callback2 within render_GET(), an exception raised anywhere within render_GET will produce the desired stack trace.

I am trying to write code that will respond to the browser immediately, not cause resource leaks within Twisted, and cause the browser stack trace to also be displayed in the cases where any of the raise statements "E1" to "E3" is included in the deferred code--though of course I understand that the stack traces themselves will be different.  (The "E4" case I don't care about as much.)  After reading the Twisted documentation and other questions on this site I am unsure how to achieve this.  I would have thought that adding an errback should facilitate this, but evidently not.  There must be something about Deferred objects and the twisted.web stack that I'm not understanding.

The effects on logging I document here may be affected by my use of the PythonLoggingObserver to bridge Twisted logging to the standard logging module.

When "E1" is included, the browser waits until the reactor is shut down, at which point the ValueError exception with stack trace is logged and the browser receives an empty document.

When "E2" is included, the ValueError exception with stack trace is logged immediately, but the browser waits until the reactor shuts down at which point it receives an empty document.

When "E3" is included, the ValueError exception with stack trace is logged immediately, the browser waits until the reactor shuts down, and at that point receives the intended document.

When raise statement "E4" is included, the intended document is returned to the browser immediately, and the ValueError exception with stack trace is logged immediately.  (Is there any possibility of a resource leak in this case?)

Comment: Your `errback` method doesn't do anything. It is simply acting as a pass-thru. Returning the `failure` to the deferred will just cause the next `errback` to be called, or if its the end of the chain the failure will sit in the deferred till it gets garbage collected, then the original exception will be raised, with the original stack trace. If you wanted the trace earlier, then have you `errback` re raise the original exception and **not** return the `failure`.

Comment: If I use an errback function that simply raises ValueError again the results are unchanged from the problem statement.  The Twisted documentation seems to be telling me that raising and returning a Failure instance are equivalent in the callback/errback chain.  It seems necessary for the errback function to directly call the request.processingFailed() method to get a stack trace to the browser.

Comment: Yes sorry. If you look at my answer below you can see that I have corrected my mistake. What I meant is that you can print out the exception trace to stdout or to the log module. I didn't understand that you wanted to print the trace to the browser. In that case I will modify my answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after reading your question several times, I think I understand what your asking. I have also reworked you code to make a little better than your original answer. This new answer should show off all the powers of deferred's.

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import defer, threads
from itertools import count

class echo(resource.Resource):
  isLeaf = True
  def errback(self, failure, request):
    failure.printTraceback() # This will print the trace back in a way that looks like a python exception.
    # log.err(failure) # This will use the twisted logger. This is the best method, but
    # you need to import twisted log.

    request.processingFailed(failure) # This will send a trace to the browser and close the request.
    return None #  We have dealt with the failure. Clean it out now.

  def final(self, message, request, encoding): 
    # Message will contain the message returned by callback1
    request.write(message.encode(encoding)) # This will write the message and return it to the browser.

    request.finish() # Done

  def callback1(self, value):
    #raise ValueError  # E1
    lines = ['<html><body>\n',
             '<p>Page view #%s in this session</p>\n' % (value,),
             '</body></html>\n']
    return ''.join(lines)

    #raise ValueError  # E4

  def render_GET(self, request):
    content_type, encoding = 'text/html', 'UTF-8'
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', '%s; charset=%s' %
        tuple(map(str, (content_type, encoding))))
    s = request.getSession()
    if not hasattr(s, 'counter'):
      s.counter = count(1)
    d = threads.deferToThread(self.callback1, s.counter.next())
    d.addCallback(self.final, request, encoding)
    d.addErrback(self.errback, request) # We put this here in case the encoding raised an exception.
    #raise ValueError  # E5
    return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

Also I recommend that you read the [krondo](http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327) tutorial. It will teach you everything you need to know about deferred.

### Edit:

Have modified the code above to fix some silly bugs. Also improved it. If an exception happens anywhere (except in `self.errback`, but we need some level of trust) then it will be passed to `self.errback` which will log or print the error in twisted and then send the trace to the browser *and* close the request. This should stop any resource leaks.

Comment: Yes, I think this does capture the essence of it.  Although returning None from errback would, according to my understanding of the callback chain, make an invocation of self.final(None) possible in the case of an exception before callback1 was called.  Regardless, I think this illustrates how a decorator or dynamic Resource subclass factory could be written with "your blocking method here" substituted for callback1, and with semantics preserved in the case of exceptions.

Comment: No, returning `None` will never cause any other callback to be called. This is because of the order that the callbacks are added. When you use `deferred.addCallback` it adds the call to the callback chain, and a pass-thru to the errback chain. So if you look at the order the `errback` will always be called last. Read [this](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1682) and [this](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1825) for a more detailed explanation of how callbacks and errbacks work.

Comment: I later found that the final and errback functions in this answer execute in the main reactor thread, potentially leading to bottlenecks.  So in my implementation I have a "delegate" decorator that calls deferToThread on the given function when called, and I use it on not only the render_GET() but also on the callback and errback functions.

Comment: I relies that this question probably became obsolete months ago, however I have only just noticed the reply and feel compelled to reply in turn.

By using deferToThread you have completely missed the point of twisted and asynchronous programming. By using things like the request object twisted ensures no bottle-necks by ensuring that anything that could block it handed to the OS to deal with (not quite true but close enough). Also any CPU bound tasks don't gain in Python due to the global interpreter lock which ensures only one Python thread runs at a time.

Comment: I was using multiple threads primarily to handle blocking calls, not to speed up computations.  So the GIL was not a big concern.  Since my callback chain was performing blocking calls (writing to the request object to send the response), that was sometimes making other requests wait, so I delegated them to threads.  Practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by digging through the Twisted source.  The necessary insight is that the reactor and Deferred callback/errback chain logic is decoupled from the request object, which is how data gets back to the browser.  The errback is necessary, but cannot merely propagate the Failure object down the chain as in the original code I posted.  The errback must report the error to the browser.

The below code meets my requirements (never keeps the browser waiting, always gives the stack trace, does not require a reactor restart to get things going again) and will allow me to decorate blocking methods and thereby delegate them to threads to keep the reactor responsive to other events (such methods will essentially take the place of callback1 here).  However, I did find that in the below code, uncommenting the "E4" raise statement produces very strange behavior on subsequent browser requests (partial data from previous requests returned to the browser; deadlock).

Hopefully others will find this to be a useful Deferred example.

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import defer, threads
from itertools import count

class echo(resource.Resource):
  isLeaf = True
  def errback(self, request):
    def execute(failure):
      request.processingFailed(failure)
      return failure
    return execute
  def callback1(self, value):
    #raise ValueError  # E1
    lines = ['<html><body>\n',
             '<p>Page view #%s in this session</p>\n' % (value,),
             '</body></html>\n']
    return ''.join(lines)
  def callback2(self, request, encoding):
    def execute(message):
      #raise ValueError  # E2
      request.write(message.encode(encoding))
      #raise ValueError  # E3
      request.finish()
      #raise ValueError  # E4
      return server.NOT_DONE_YET
    return execute
  def render_GET(self, request):
    content_type, encoding = 'text/html', 'UTF-8'
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', '%s; charset=%s' %
        tuple(map(str, (content_type, encoding))))
    s = request.getSession()
    if not hasattr(s, 'counter'):
      s.counter = count(1)
    d = threads.deferToThread(self.callback1, s.counter.next())
    eback = self.errback(request)
    d.addErrback(eback)
    d.addCallback(self.callback2(request, encoding))
    d.addErrback(eback)
    #raise ValueError  # E5
    return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```